# When to use each model relationship in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I've been reading through the Django documentation and looking over some of the other answers on the site for a couple of hours now, yet I still can't get it to sink in. I know this isn't Django specific, but the examples I use will be from a Django project.

My question boils down to when is it appropriate to use each:

- Many-to-many relationships
- Many-to-one relationships
- One-to-one relationships

**One-to-one**, more or less makes sense to me.

Now for the other two. While I understand the differences between them in isolation, when it comes to using them practically in a project, I get confused. Here is an example:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='watchlist', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Listing)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Would this be the correct use of **Many-to-one(ForeignKey)** and **Many-to-many?**

1. Should Watchlist.item be a ForeignKey? Or is M2M correct?
2. Wouldn't it simplify to make the 'Watchlist' part of the User class? (give them an empty list to populate with listing ID's)
3. Why is Watchlist.user not a One-to-one relationship, if each watchlist belongs to a single user, and a user can only have one list?

Apologies for my stupidity, I just can't get this to sink in!

**Thank you.**

edit: Context, the models are from a 'learning' project I was working on intended to be an auction site, similar to eBay. The watchlist is sort of a 'wish' list... for the user to watch an item, not for site to watch a user!

Comment: I don't know what a listing is, to you. If it is your intention to only relate one user to one watchlist (sounds scary..) then it is so, namely a 1:1 relation. You ask why it is not a 1:1, well that is because you have written down that it is a 1:M? This is your code, so that was a little odd - you are the boss here. So if one user can have one watchlist, I guess this one watchlist can have many listings? That would be a 1:M relation.

Comment: I've added a little more context to what a listing is, and the watchlist... it's not scary haha. Regarding my third question, setting it up as is in my code seemed to be the conclusion I got from reading other examples, but I seem to have just confused myself even more! I think I'm slowly learning there is no one answer fits all for databases, and design choices need to be made as the project evolves. I'll definitely go back and spend more time on the underlying SQL. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To explain it simply these django-models or objects represents tables in your database and the fields are like the columns in them. So with a one-to-one relation you can only have one row in one table relating to one row in another table. For example one user in the user table (represented by one row) can only relate to one row in a profile table. But your user can have many comments, so this would be a one-to-many/foreignkey relation (if you set unique=true on a fk, it will in practice function as 1:1). If the users can collaborate on writing comments, or for example as here on stackoverflow where users can edit other users comments, that would be a many-to-many relation.

Database design can be complicated/complex, especially using an ORM without basic knowledge of SQL and how it all works beneath. In general it requires a bit of planning even for a simple application.